# Find rows that contain same value inside comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, sql-server-2014

I have a varchar column, populated by another process where I have no control over, that is filled with comma separated values.

Now I need to find all rows where part of this column exists in that same column, in another row

example

```
declare @table table (value varchar(50))
insert into @table values ('NB,BD,FR'), ('BD,GK'), ('SL,SR')

select * from @table
```

so the table contains

```
value   
-----   
NB,BD,FR    
BD,GK   
SL,SR
```

from the example above I would like to get

```
value   
-----   
NB,BD,FR    
BD,GK
```

Because there is a value (in this case `BD` but can be anything) present in both rows

Can this be done in sql?

Comment: There may be some way of doing this directly and it would work fine for the example given but bear in mind that the cost for this kind of searches is clearly exponential and if you have a few thousand rows you system will be frozen. Better to split (normalize) the data and even then the cost will be high but much lower than doing directly.

Comment: @AngelM. I whish I could normalize it. This table is populated by another process where I have no control over. I need to read this table like it is unfortunate. The only good thing is that is will never have more than about 100 rows in it

Comment: Good !!! On this case it looks like you already have some correct answer.

Comment: I'd caution you here - whenever I catch myself saying things "will never have more than..." they almost inevitably grow. Is there a way for you to create another table and transform this data into normalized data? I understand where you're coming from; I just had flashbacks to past problems when I read your comment.

Comment: @jwheron I understand your concern. This is a detail table that holds types of cars that should be transported. Unless each brand will create thousands of types I think I can assume master/Detail combination will have only a few hundred rows

Comment: @AngelM. Yes the accepted answer will do, but if you know an alternative I am always interested

Comment: The idea that I was going to propose is not so good as the one proposed by Salman. So, just use SELECT DISTINCT value instead of SELECT value to ensure you don't show duplicates as in case you add a line like for example ,('GK,SR') it would show some duplicates.

Comment: @AngelM.Yes i added the distinct and I am already using this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use clunky XML manipulation to convert comma separated values to rows:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (value VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('NB,BD,FR'),
('BD,GK'),
('SL,SR');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT value, node.value('.', 'varchar(10)') AS substr
    FROM @table
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(value, ',', '</x>,<x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS x(doc)
    CROSS APPLY doc.nodes('/x') AS n(node)
)
-- use your favorite technique to find the duplicate
SELECT value
FROM cte AS m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cte AS x
    WHERE value <> m.value AND substr = m.substr
)
```

The `CAST(... AS XML)` part assumes that your data does not contain characters that have special meaning in XML. The [`nodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method will convert one row to many, rest is straight forward.

Comment: Just add DISTINCT to "SELECT value" as if you try with some dataset that produces duplicates this way will produce duplicates. By the way, congratulations Salman, great solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong data structure.  Don't store values in strings!

```
declare @table table (id int, value varchar(50));
insert into @table
    values (1, 'NB'), (1, 'BD'), (1, 'FR'),
           (2, 'BD'), (2, 'GK'),
           (3, 'SL'), (3, 'SR');
```

Then you can get what you want using window functions:

```
 select id, value
 from (select t.*, max(cnt) over (partition by id) as max_cnt
       from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by value) as cnt
             from @table t
            ) t
      ) t
 where max_cnt >= 2
```

Comment: I know its not good to store values in strings. The column is populated by another process I have no control over. But thanks for the answer